# Всплывающая подсказка в EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

Добрый день!
Интересует возможность отображения всплывающей подсказки для конкретной строки, а лучше конкретного слова в EditText (например отобразить рядом (над/под конкретным словом произвольный компонент еще один EditText или Spinner).

Подскажите, каким образом можно реализовать (определить координаты строки, слова).

Comment: Что именно Вы подразумеваете под всплывающими подсказками ?

Comment: МОжет быть вам надо использовать editText.setError(text)?

Comment: например EditText содержит многострочный текст и в какой-то момент необходимо отобразить некий текст/слово над или под интересующим словом

Comment: editText.setError(text) - тоже вариант,  если заполнять Layout "массивом" EditText - где каждый из элементов EditText = слово из текста. В нужный момент и для нужного слова вызывать setError()

Answer (score 2):

Если я подумал о тех подсказках под полем `EditText`, то нужно использовать `TextInputLayout`:

Пример кода:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/hint_password_field" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

В `android:hint` задаете подсказку для своего `EditText`, а `TextInputLayout` будет ее подымать вверх, когда юзер поставит фокус на Ваш EditText.

Надеюсь, что это именно то.

Comment: TextInputLayout, думаю что можно применить следующим образом
Заполнять Layout "массивом" TextInputLayout - где каждый из TextInputLayout = слово из текста.  В нужный момент android:hint присваивать "подсказку"